# JavaFX ignores weight and style from custom fonts

Tags: java, css, javafx, fonts, font-style

When I make javafx load a font with a code like this:

```
font = Font.loadFont(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("gui/font.ttf").toExternalForm(), 25);
```

and, after it has successfully loaded, apply it to a Text

```
text.setFont(font);
```

the text shows the right font BUT, when I try to apply to it some styles or weights like

```
text.setStyle("-fx-font-weight: bold;");
```

or

```
text.setStyle("-fx-font-style: italic;");
```

Nothing changes.
I've tried this even with the SceneBuilder and It doesn't work there too.
What can I do to make java load my font WITH all the styles and weights (or, at least, make it try to derive them)?

EDIT: fount used: [Peque Script](http://www.dafont.com/peque-script.font) (I know, 5 minutes ago it wasn't in maintenance)
Some other fonts found online like [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/844v64a9d8m40zm/minecraftfont.woff?dl=0) or [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/alt49zdl5ee2se3/minecraftia.ttf?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with a random one and is working, i think it is due to the Font that you use, it may not have a weight, what Font you are using ? (can't comment).

Edit :
i've done a little research, and i've found that only one (individual/united) Style is present in a ".tff" file even if it's a rich file. If you take the example of "consolas" Font, there is 4 types (Normal/Italic/Bold/Bold-Italic), these types are used together but in separate files. I hope this answered your question.

Comment: Yes but in java.awt.Font there is something to derive fonts, and it is in every other normal api/application, isn't there any way to derive bold or italic? (even if it should do it on his own)